# Enter key disabled on Linux box

Tags: linux, key, enter

I have ssh'd into a linux box and for some reason cannot hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run any command (such as `pwd`). I can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when there is no text on the prompt, but any time any text is in the prompt, it seems <kbd>Enter</kbd> is disabled. Could this be some kind of security measure? I've tried this in putty and cygwin, and both exhibit this behavior. how can I enable they <kbd>Enter</kbd> key so that I can run commands on this box?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Please ask for it to be migrated to superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>  intead of enter.